# Apache Nifi to move files to new hdfs folder for the files lesser than current date

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh, mapr, data-ingestion

I am creating end to end flow to consume data into HDFS by using Consume Kafka for the Json files received through tealium event stream.

Currently, I have used

```
Consume Kafka -> Evaluate Json Path -> Jolttransform Json -> Merge Content -> Evaluate Json Path -> Update attribute -> PutHDFS ->MoveHDFS
```

The requirement is to read JSON Data for entire day spool into a single file referring to attribute postdate(covert epoch to `YYYYMMDDSS` timestamp before) and read data daily to merge into a single output file and finally rename the file as per the Timestamp related to POST_DATE field to differentiate daily files.

The current date output folder should have only current date processing files and all the completed output file for earlier dates should move to a different folder.

Could you please help me how to work on MoveHDFS to recursively search the hdfs folder and move completed output files not equal to current date to move into a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

The current flow worked fine.
Consume Kafka -> Evaluate Json Path -> Jolttransform Json -> Merge Content -> Evaluate Json Path -> Update attribute -> PutHDFS ---> To create merge file.

Create a separate flow once the above flow is done to receive the processed merge file and re-process it with listhdfs->fethchdfs->updateattribute->puthdfs

In the listhdfs, set the minimum file age wait time before consuming. This will allow the process to search files recursively and also use updateattribute to re-create the folder as per the parent folder to re-use the process file.